# Design editor is Unavailable Until after successful project sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am new to Android and when I tried to design UI in design editor for the first app I faced an error "Design editor is Unavailable Until after successful project sync", then I realized that I had also issues in sync panel and that was all about dependencies in `build.gradle`. How should I change dependencies to solve this issue? Below are dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

And below are sync errors:

```
ERROR:Failed to resolve:junit
ERROR:Failed to resolve:epresso-idling-source
ERROR:Failed to resolve:runner
ERROR:Failed to resolve:core
ERROR:Failed to resolve:epresso-core
ERROR:Failed to resolve:monitor
```

Comment: Edit Your question and add the Error that You get when You sync Gradle.

Comment: i get below errors when i try to sync gradle:  Error:Failed to resolve :Runner,,Core,,espresso-core,, monitor

Comment: It has to be something else, I copied Your dependencies and didn't get any error

Comment: thank you for dedicating your time.testimplemenatation parts caused that issue,and by deleting three lines including them i could solve the problem,but i dont know why this should happan.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed these below lines from dependencies and it worked,

> ```
> testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
> ```

but i dont know that will cause an issue in future or not..